# Finding full path of a symlink'ed file (more quickly)?

Tags: directory, symbolic-link

[image]

Under `Properties` dialog window: `Link target:` the path of the original file is always shortened, due to a programed restriction of characters space, even after resizing the window, and therefore of not much use.

When the `Link target` path is copied and pasted to a terminal window, it looks like this:

```
../../lib/firefox/icons/mozicon128.png
```

which is a small improvement, since now the original file name is fully know and `locate mozicon128.png` will provide the correct path, which is:

```
/usr/lib/firefox/icons/mozicon128.png
```

**Q1:** What other options are there to find the path more quickly, without using the suggested two steps (maybe a right-click menu integration that copies the path to clipboard would be great)?!

**Q2:** `../../` refers to `/` (see screenshot below), but why, instead of being more accurate? Is there any build in option, to copy the full path from Properties dialog window (Ubuntu 11.10)?

[image]

---

Path of the symlinked firefox image in this example is:

```
/usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `namei` utility is exactly what you want.

From `man namei`:

```
   namei  uses  its arguments as pathnames to any type of Unix file (symlinks, files,
   directories, and so forth).  namei then follows each pathname until an endpoint is
   found  (a file, a directory, a device node, etc).  If it finds a symbolic link, it
   shows the link, and starts following it, indenting the output to show the context.

   This program is useful for finding "too many levels of symbolic links" problems.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [nautilus script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) for this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Remove line feed at the end of the path
selectedPath="${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS%?}"

# Check if the selected file is a symbolic link
if [ -h "$selectedPath" ]; then
    symlinkPath=$( readlink "$selectedPath" )
else
    zenity --info --text="$( basename "$selectedPath" ) is not a symbolic link"
    exit 0
fi

# Copy the the symbolic link into the clipboard
echo "$symlinkPath" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

More about readlink -> http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/readlink.1.html

You have to install `xclip` for this if not already done.

Comment: thank you for your answer Tuknutx. It works too as well. +1